# elasticsearch equivalent of EmbeddedSolrServer for Solr

Tags: elasticsearch, solrj

Is it possible to update index built using elastic search without the overheads of http and serialization?
I am searching for an elasticsearch equivalent of EmbeddedSolrServer available with solrj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it is, with elasticsearch you can easily start up a local node and embed it in your application.

With local node I mean with local discovery, local within the jvm.

Have a look at the [Java API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/java-api/client/) documentation, where there's an example on how to  startup a local node:

```
Node node = nodeBuilder().local(true).node();
Client client = node.client();
```

Don't forget to shut it down when you're done:

```
node.close();
```

Have a look at this blog I wrote too: [elasticsearch beyond big data - running elasticsearch embedded](http://blog.trifork.com/2012/09/13/elasticsearch-beyond-big-data-running-elasticsearch-embedded/).